# strange xrange() behavior in Python 2

Tags: python

I am familiar with the difference between `range()` and `xrange()`. I noticed something weird with `xrange()`:

```
>>> xrange(1,10,2)
xrange(1, 11, 2)

>>> xrange(1,10,4)
xrange(1, 13, 4)
```

Functionally, it is correct:

```
>>> for item in xrange(1,10,4):
...     print item
... 
1
5
9
>>>
```

However, as you can see, the stop value in the returned `xrange` object is the next higher value after the last legal value. Any reason why?

`range()` which now provides the same functionality in Python 3 as `xrange` in Python 2 behaves as expected:

```
>>> range(1,10,4)
range(1, 10, 4)
>>> range(1,10,2)
range(1, 10, 2)
>>>
```

Comment: No, `xrange()` is not the same as `range()` in python 3. The latter is a new type. The end value is *never* included in either `range()` or `xrange()`. Because of your `step` value, neither `11` nor `10` are included in the range output anyway.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I agree with your first half of the comment. Edited my question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Now, regarding the stop value never included, yes I know that. Why is the xrange object returned with a stop value as the last legal value + step ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`xrange(1, 10, 4)` is equivalent to `xrange(1, 13, 4)`. To use your example:

```
>>> for item in xrange(1,13,4):
...     print item
... 
1
5
9
>>>
```

`xrange` in Python 2 canonicalizes the `start, stop, step` arguments. Internally, the `xrange` implementation stores the triple start, step and length (number of elements in the `xrange` object) instead of start, step and stop. Here is how `xrange.__repr__()` is implemented [1]:

```
rtn = PyString_FromFormat("xrange(%ld, %ld, %ld)",
                          r->start,
                          r->start + r->len * r->step,
                          r->step);
```

[1] https://github.com/replit/empythoned/blob/master/cpython/Objects/rangeobject.c

Comment: Great. Thanks for sharing the link to the CPython source.

Comment: I am accepting your answer, since it is precisely what my question was.

Comment: This is the link to the official CPython 3.3 source: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/e45db319e590/Objects/rangeobject.c#l808

Comment: And the CPython 2.7 source: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/4edde40afee6/Objects/rangeobject.c#l133

Answer (score 4):

The stop value of a `range` or `xrange` is always exclusive.

Quote from the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range) (Python 2):

> If `step` is positive, the last element is the largest `start + i * step` **less than** `stop`; if `step` is negative, the last element is the smallest `start + i * step` **greater than** `stop`.

And for [Python 3](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#range):

> For a positive `step`, the contents of a range r are determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i` where `i >= 0` and **`r[i] < stop`**.
>
> For a negative `step`, the contents of the range are still determined by the formula `r[i] = start + step*i`, but the constraints are `i >= 0` and **`r[i] > stop`**.

---

About the second part of your question regarding the `repr()` of the `xrange`:

`xrange(1, 10, 4)` and `xrange(1, 13, 4)` are identical and `repr()` for native python objects usually returns valid python code to recreate the object. This does not need to be the exactly same python code that initially created the object.

Comment: Yes, I will accept your answer since the second half of the answer is what I was looking for. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, I accepted @zodiac's answer since he even pointed me to the source code which gives me the exact answer I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Does it really matter?

The *effect* is the same. Neither 10 nor 11 is included in the output of `xrange()`, and `xrange(1, 11, 2)` is *equivalent* to `xrange(1, 10, 2)`.

The Python 2 range type (the result of `xrange()`) stores the range length, not the end value, so to create the `repr` output it calculates that end value for you. And because you used a step value, the calculation shows the result of the formula `start + length * step`. For the implementation, the length is the more important value, the `end` value can safely be discarded and recalculated as needed.

So, when you create `xrange(1, 10, 2)`, it calculates the range length and stores *that* instead of the end value:

```
if (step > 0 && lo < hi)
return 1UL + (hi - 1UL - lo) / step;
else if (step < 0 && lo > hi)
return 1UL + (lo - 1UL - hi) / (0UL - step);
else
return 0UL;
```

The Python 3 Range object stores the end value *in addition* to the length, so you can query the object for it and display it in the `repr` output.

Comment: I am not sure why you ask "Does it really matter?". I Know the effect is the same. That's not what I asked. Anyway.